# Pandas: modifying the dataframe by splitting into columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which contains the number of sold cars within 2017.
I want a time series to plot different car models sold.

Here is my current DF

```
      Date   Price  Location Type               
2003-05-16  397500  Texas    Ford
2003-05-16  235000  Florida  Fiat   
2003-05-16  235000  Florida  Mercedes   
2003-05-16  235000  NJ       Mercedes
```

I want to modify the data so I get the following dataframe in order to display a multiple time series graph.

```
Date       Ford       Fiat  Mercedes            
2003-05-16  1        3       19     
2003-09-10  2        2       1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need:

```
df.groupby(['Date','Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plo‌​t.bar()
```

Or:

```
df.reset_index().groupby(['Date','Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plo‌​t.bar()
```